# How Google Cloud build works?

Tags: google-cloud-build

I am new to Google cloud build, I want to build an application which runs on Windows server. I am not using any containerized application for webhosting.Is it necessary build steps written in cloudbuild.yaml to run on container, as most of the examples I saw from Google doc's for dockerized build. If not please let me know how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

All build steps are containers that are executed as part of your pipeline, so your build itself is a containerized tool chain. However, you need not build containers -- you can build jars, pars, zip files, and anything else you might want. Export these artifacts yourself in a build step or declare them as [artifacts](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.Artifacts).

Comment: Is there any way I can build my artifact using Google cloud build on Windows Server2012 r2 container (if possible, not sure as container service starts from server 2016 core.) after installing my required packages inside it. I am bit unsure about build generated from Linux machine as some libraries may differ for windows.

Comment: At this time, build steps can only be run in a linux container. However, some users use a "remote builder" to remote to any machine you want and run something there, including to a Windows machine: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder